# Set Max filesize in PHP7 on Ubuntu16 Running Nginx

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, upload, filesize, php-7

I have changed the following lines in

```
vi /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini

upload_max_filesize = 24M
post_max_size = 32M
```

I run

```
service nginx restart
and
systemctl restart php7.0-fpm.service
```

but it does not seem to update in my phpinfo  - it still says 2M.

Answer (score 1):

It's the wrong .ini

```
vi /etc/php/7.0/fpm/php.ini
```

this works.